# How to install a VPN when it's censored itself?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I've got 2 questions:

1. I just installed ubuntu and I wanted to install a VPM on it . (proton vpn) but the government of the country that I'm living in filters access to the VPNs. And I couldn't download that VPN through terminal.
   I also couldn't install the TOR browser.
2. What is the best VPN for ubuntu?

This is one of the errors I am receiving:

> Err:10 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease Could not connect to repo.protonvpn.com:443 (d0::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

Comment: You do not need to install a VPN client. Ubuntu Desktop already includes one. However, your ISP may prevent access to the VPN server. The "best" VPN is whatever you understand how to safely and effectively use.

Comment: Ubuntu desktop already includes one ? really ? is there any way that i can connect to vpn server even though my ISP prevents it ?

Comment: Ubuntu includes a VPN **client**.  If you cannot access the server from your ISP, it doesn't matter what client you use.

Comment: now i can connect to tor browser . i couldn't install it with terminal so i just downloaded it's tar.gz file . and also proton vpn works here . ( I had proton vpn on windows until yesterday and it worked perfectly) . but the problem is for logging in proton vpn account through terminal , first i have to turn on another VPN . when i'm logged in , it work perfectly .